# Understanding the notion of approximate tangent space, with examples

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

I am studying geometric measure theory, and I am having some trouble understanding how to deal with approximate tangent spaces. I would like an example/exhibition of an approximate tangent space in a regular setting (so that it does coincide with a classic vector subspace).

First of all, the definition. We say that a Radon measure $\mu$ defined on $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has a k-ats (k approximate tangent space) in $x\in \Omega$ if $\rho^{-k} \mu_{x,\rho} \rightharpoonup^* \theta \mathcal{H}^k |_{\pi}$ as $\rho \to 0$, where $\mu_{x,\rho}(A)= \mu(x + \rho A)$, $\mathcal{H}^k$ is the k-th dimensional Hausdorff measure, $\pi$ is a k-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\theta>0$ is the so called "multiplicity".

So, let's say I have these two examples: $S_1=S^{2} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $S_2=\{y=x^2\} \cup \{y=-x^2\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. I want to calculate the approximate tangent space in $(0,1)$ of $S_1$ and in $(0,0)$ of $S_2$. First of all: who is $\mu$ in these cases? The standard Lebesgue measure? Or the curve measure given by the parametrization? I know intuitively that in the first case I should get the tangent plane in $(0,1)$ as a 2-atp and in the second case I should get the x-axis with multiplicity 2 (and if I put $n$ parabolas tangent to the origin, that would be the multiplicity), but how can I formalize this?

P.S. What could be an example of a set with non integer multiplicity at some point?

Comment: What is meant by "but how can I formalize this"? The question is somewhat vague. Maybe consider edits. That aside, since we cheatingly know from smooth manifold theory that the tangent at (0,1) is the 2D plane that is the tangent space in the usual sense, the tangent measure will be the 2D Hausdorff measure restricted to this tangent plane. In the second example, 2 times $\mathcal{H}^1$ restricted to x-axis will be the tangent measure.

Comment: I mean, how can I prove that effectively, do that for real.  As for who is the measure, I was wondering who is the $\mu$ I should consider to obtain the tangent measures you pointed out, not who were the tangent measures.

Comment: Now that you have a candidate for the limit, you must use definition of weak convergence of measure (or some lemmas that yield this convergence) to prove what you know should be true.

Comment: Ok but, again,  who is $\mu$? Who is the $\mu$ I should consider to get those limits? I'd say the 2 dimensional Hausdorff measure restricted to the sphere in the first case and the 1 dimensional Hausdorff measure restricted to $S_2$ in the second. But even if I got this $\mu$ right, I am really not sure how to prove the thesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think part of the confusion comes from the fact that the approximate tangent space is fundamentally about *measures*, whereas you are asking about the approximate tangent space of *sets*.

Now there is a canonical way of associating a measure to a set $S$ of dimension $k$, which is to take the measure $\mathcal{H}^k|_S$.  Let
$\mu = \mathcal{H}^1|_{S_1}$ be the one-dimensional Hausdorff measure restricted to the unit circle.  Suppose we want to compute the approximate tangent space at the point $(0,1)$.  The reasonable guess is that the space is $\pi = \textrm{span}\{(1,0)\}$.  If this is the case, what we would need to do is show that
$$
\rho^{-1}
\mu_{x,\rho} \rightharpoonup^* \mathcal{H}^1|_\pi.  
$$
In other words, given a fixed continuous function $f\in C^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ one needs to show that
$$
\lim_{\rho\to 0} 
\rho^{-1} \int f(\rho^{-1}x,\rho^{-1} (y-1)) \,d\mu(x,y) = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,0)\,dx.
$$
I will sketch how one can prove this.  First one reduces to the case that $f$ is a smooth function of compact support,
say in the ball of radius $R$.  Then the function
$f_\rho(x,y) = f(\rho^{-1}x, \rho^{-1}(y-1))$ has support in the ball $B_{\rho R}((0,1))$ of radius $\rho R$ centered at $(0,1)$.  Then one can express $\mu$ using the parametrization
$$
\int f_\rho(x,y) \,d\mu(x,y) = 
\int_0^{2\pi} f_\rho(\cos(t),\sin(t))\,dt.
$$
One then only needs to consider the case $t$ close to $\pi/2$, for which one has the bound
$f_\rho(\cos(\pi/2 + \delta), \sin(\pi/2+\delta)) 
= f(0, \rho^{-1}\delta) + O(\delta^2)$ using a Taylor expansion and the smoothness of $f$.  A change of variables and taking the limit gives the result.

In general to study the measure $\mathcal{H}^k|_S$ for some set $S$ one needs a way to represent integration of the measure in terms of integrals you already know how to compute.  This is in general done with the area formula.  The idea is that, given a map $\Phi:B_1^k\to \mathbb{R}^d$ from the unit ball $B_1^k\subset\mathbb{R}^k$, one can express integration against the Hausdorff measure on the image of the map $\Phi$ in terms of an integral over $B_1^k$ and the Jacobian of the map $\Phi$.

Now that we have looked at a familiar example, it is worth looking at unfamiliar examples.  The simplest is the measure $\mu = f(x)dx$, where $dx$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $f$ is some continuous function.  The approximate tangent space to $\mu$ at $x$ is again going to be $\mathbb{R}^d$ *with multiplicity* $f(x)$.  In fact, we can take $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and obtain such a statement almost everywhere using the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Things can get much stranger because one can add measures of different dimensions.  For example, if $S_1$ is a one-dimensional curve, $S_2$ is a two-dimensional surface, and $S_3$ is three-dimensional, it is perfectly reasonable to consider the measure
$$
\nu = \mathcal{H}^1|_{S^1} + \mathcal{H}^2|_{S^2} + \mathcal{H}^3|_{S^3}.
$$
The approximate tangent space of this measure at a point will depend on which surface it lies on, and if the point is at an intersection of surfaces the lowest-dimensional space will dominate.
One can even then multiply such a measure by a smooth function to get non-integer multiplicities.